# How to include a Qt Core c++ class for use in QtScript user function in SQLiteStudio 3.1.1?

Tags: qt, base64, qtscript, sqlitestudio

I'm trying to write a user-defined function within SQLiteStudio (v3.1.1). This function needs to decode a field stored in base64.

I think I can achieve what I want to using the `QByteArray` class from Qt Core  like so:

```
QByteArray text = QByteArray::fromBase64(base64EncodedString);
return text.data();
```

But how can I include/import the `QByteArray` class, so I can access it's methods inside my user-defined function? Is this even possible within SQLiteStudio?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible in SQLiteStudio, but is there a reason why you can't use SQLS' own base64_decode(arg) function?

Comment: @TimSmit Doh! Thanks, I should have RTFM! I'd done some googling, but hadn't seen that it was built-in! If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it. Maybe include a link to the [sqlitestudio user-manual](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/User_Manual)

Comment: I also didn't find it that easily but couldn't imagine it not existing, so I checked more :) Would appreciate if you could accept, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible in SQLiteStudio, but you should be able to use SQLS' own base64_decode(arg) function.